# property sheet handlers on Windows 10

Tags: windows, shell-extensions

I have developed a custom property sheet handler that works fine on Windows 7 and Windows 8.  On Windows 10, it is not loaded.  It appear there were changes in the registration of shell extensions in Windows 10, though I haven't tracked down the specifics.

My property sheet handler reads custom XMP data from jpeg files (.jpe or .jpeg).  If I register a new file type (i.e., .photo extension) and register my handler for that, it works as expected:

```
HKCR\.photo\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{my class id}
```

However, if I register it for the existing jpeg file type (jpegfile), it is not loaded:

```
HKCR\jpegfile\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{my class id}
```

Again, this issue only occurs on Windows 10.  The handler works fine when registered under the HKCR\jpegfile key type on Windows 7 and 8.  Anyone aware of what may have changed with Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Try registering like below:

```
HKCR\.jpeg\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{my class id}
HKCR\.jpg\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{my class id}
```

Answer (score 0):

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` seems to be [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (HKCR) key contains file name extension
>   associations and COM class registration information such as ProgIDs,
>   CLSIDs, and IIDs. **It is primarily intended for compatibility with the
>   registry in 16-bit Windows**.

Please move your keys to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` (or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` for the current user).

Comment: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is simply a shortcut to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.  Making an entry in one is automatically reflected in the other

Comment: It is actually a combined key, representing the values in both `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. Because this happens transparent to the user, you may not be aware which key you are actually changing: *If you write values to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and the key already exists under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes, the system will store the information there instead of under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.*

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Alas, that suggestion did not work (adding the keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes rather than HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes).

Comment: Have you made separate 32bit and 64bit versions of your handler DLL? Windows/File Explorer will load whichever DLL matches its own bitness, so you need a 64bit DLL for 64bit Explorer, and a 32bit DLL for 32bit Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, you have to write an entry in the registry for each file extension you want to handle, for example: `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations﻿\.jpeg\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers`. Create a subkey with your property sheet handler having his CLISD as default value.